# How can i ping a Computer or a Printer using its Mac address?

Tags: command-line, ping

Suppose I have a printer in my network has a **Mac Address** : **11:22:33:44:55:66** .

Is there a way i can **ping** it to see if its **up** or **down** using its **Mac address** ?

Any Help ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some research i have succeeded in pinging  my printer by its **mac-address** by following these steps using `arping` tool :

First I tried `arping` that is installed by default in Ubuntu 12.04 , it state `unknown host` whenever I ping a Mac Address .

I search for the problem and found that newer version of **arping** stopped this feature .

I search for an old version i found **Thomas habets arping**. Download It from [Herer](http://linux.softpedia.com/progDownload/Arping-Download-13515.html)  .

After Download extract it .

Before installation make sure you download **libnet** [Here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libnet/1.1.2.1-2build1) , and **libcap-dev**

```
sudo apt-get install libpcap-dev
```

Now it time to install `arping 2.13` , open Terminal :

```
cd /path/to/arpingfolder

./configure

make

make install
```

Now  Navigate to :

```
cd /usr/local/sbin/
```

And run the following command :

```
arping -i (your network interface ) -c 3 11:22:33:44:55:66
```

[image]

For more options type `man arping`.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that current (in January 2020) releases of Debian Devuan, and Ubuntu carry two versions of arping in their repositories.

Current packages:

'arping' is the 'traditional' version maintained by Thomas Habets, currently v:2.19

```
apt-get install arping
```

while 'iputils-arping' is the version which no longer supports MAC address pings.

```
apt-get install iputils-arping
```

As written by the package maintainers, installing one removes the other.

Just be aware that you may need to re-login after installation to avoid the command caching that some releases use...  After installing I was getting '/usr/bin/arping: No such file or directory' until I re-logged in.